# Executable gets suspended when called from batch script

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch

I have a set of batch files running under Windows 7 and Windows 10 and while they are doing just fine in the former, I'm having issues in the latter.
Basically, one of the exe files called by the batch gets suspended and never returns when the batch is run under Windows 10.
This happens systematically under Windows 10 and I can see the process is suspended with the Task Manager showing it to me.

As this is in a batch file, I tried the same call with the same parameters outside, directly in a `cmd.exe` process. But in that case, the exe is NOT suspended!

I really can't figure out why Windows 10 would suspend my process, nor why it would only do so when it gets called inside a batch file.

Would any of you have any clues/hints as to what would be causing this?
Any suggestion as to what I should try to identify the culprit?

Comment: When you run it as a test, are you running it as the same account as when it executes in Task Manager?

Comment: Yes, same user, same session

Comment: Does the user have log on as a batch job/intereactive privilege? Task manager executed scripts sometimes need that depending on what they are doing.

Comment: I'm not executing via Task manager, Task manager is only used to see what processes are running and what state they are in. 
All this is started from a Explorer window, not from any scheduler.

Comment: does your batch file have an `exit` in it? from my experience the batch not exiting properly is what causes anything else you execute to hang

Comment: @OBones The references to Task Manager actually refer to task scheduler in my and Smock's comments

Comment: What user context is the scheduled task running in?  Is it System or a named windows user?

Comment: @uSlackr Once again, the batch is not run via the scheduler, it's run directly from a command line window. The Task Manager is the windows too that you get when pressing Ctrl-Shitf-Escape and which displays the list of running processes. In that list, I see one that gets suspended and I can't explain why.

Comment: I know the difference between Task Manager and Task Scheduler. I misunderstood that the process isn’t being run as a scheduled task. Perhaps you could share exactly what you are trying to run. It could help

Comment: Can you share the batch file or a part of it where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

After testing various things with a colleague, we found out that the exe would not get suspended if the batch and the files it works on are placed inside a "short" location. 
For instance, it works inside `c:\folder` but not inside `c:\users\obones\Documents\folder`

This lead to the discovery of a workaround by changing the way the `for` loop that calls the suspended exe is written.
Initially, I had this:

```
for %%l in (%COMMON_SOURCE_POS% ignore.po) do call :RemoveIgnored %%l
```

where the `COMMON_SOURCE_POS` is a (rather long) list of space separated quoted file names, most of them being absolute file names, that is, ones with full paths. For instance `"c:\folder\common\subfolder\..\..\someotherfolder\somename.po"`

Now, the code is this:

```
set COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME=common_source_pos.txt
echo.> %COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME%
for %%p in (%COMMON_SOURCE_POS%) do if /I %%~np neq %TARGET% echo %%p>> %COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME%
echo ignore.po>> %COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME%

for /F "delims=;" %%l in (%COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME%) do call :RemoveIgnored %%l
del %COMMON_SOURCE_POS_FILENAME%
```

With this, the exe that is called by the `:RemoveIgnored` subpart no longer gets suspended by Windows 10.

I am not sure why this helps, but clearly this has to do with the length of variables that are used by the `for` command.